# Syntax error in Postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I written select query in PostgreSQL DB but it is giving me syntax error.

```
select order.c_doctype_id , doc.DocSubTypeSO 
from c_order order 
    inner join c_doctype doc on(order.c_doctype_id = doc.c_doctype_id)
where order.c_order_id =1000674
```

In above query it giving me syntax error near order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes `""` for reserved words :

```
select "order".c_doctype_id , doc.DocSubTypeSO 
from c_order "order"
inner join c_doctype doc on("order".c_doctype_id = doc.c_doctype_id)
where "order".c_order_id =1000674
```

Or just don't use reserved words:

```
select o.c_doctype_id , doc.DocSubTypeSO 
from c_order o
inner join c_doctype doc on(o.c_doctype_id = doc.c_doctype_id)
where o.c_order_id =1000674
```